# Удалить из возвращаемого вложенного массива некоторые значения

Tags: php, laravel, oracle

Мне возвращается ответ  из сторонней проги, в виде вложенного массива, и из всего этого вложенного массива нужно убрать определенные ненужные значения, оставив лишь нужные, пример возвращаемого массива такой:

```
 //Controller 

public function getDictiEconomic()
{
    $economicIsn = 987;
    $result = $this->service->getDictiEconomic($economicIsn);
    return response()->json([
        'economicIsn' => $result,
        'code' => 200
    ]);
}

 //Service

public function getDictiEconomic($economicIsn)
 {
    return $this->oracleBd->getDictiDc($economicIsn);
 }

 //Oracle procedure

  public function getDictiDc($isn)
{
    try {
        $procedure = $this->pdo->prepare("begin insdyr.web_methods.GetDictiList(:vId, :vCursor); end;");
        $procedure->bindParam(":vISN", $isn, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $procedure->bindParam(":vCursor", $cursor, PDO::PARAM_STMT, 10000);
        $procedure->execute();
        oci_execute($cursor, OCI_DEFAULT);
        oci_fetch_all($cursor, $result, 0, -1, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW + OCI_ASSOC);
        oci_free_cursor($cursor);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new SystemException('procedure params invalid for getDictiEconomic ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    return $result;

}

   {
      "economicIsn": [
       {
        "ISN": "7675677",
        "PARENTISN": "976",
        "CODE": "9",
        "NUMCODE": null,
        "SHORTNAME": "tyrtyrtyrtyrtyrtyrt",
        "FULLNAME": "rtyrtyrtyrtyrtyrtyrtyrty",
        "TABLENAME": null,
        "CONSTNAME": "tryrtyrtyryrtyryrtyrty",
        "N_KIDS": null,
        "ACTIVE": "N",
        "UPDATED": "2017-02-03 17:01:31",
        "UPDATEDBY": "1",
        "USERCONSTNAME": null,
        "REFCLASSISN1": null,
        "REFCLASSISN2": null,
        "REFCLASSISN3": null
    },

Следом за ним такой же массив и их может быть неопределенное кол-во, можно unset, но 
не могу понять как из-за вложенности и неизвестного кол-ва.

],
"code": 200
 }
```

И допустим из этого вложенного массива нужно удалить везде "PARENTISN" и "TABLENAME"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная с Laravel 8 есть хелпер Arr::dot() и Arr::undot()

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

...    

$flattened = \Illuminate\Support\Arr::dot($array);

$except = ['.PARENTISN', '.TABLENAME'];

foreach ($flattened as $key) {
    if(in_array($key, $except)) {
        unset($flattened[$key]);
    }
}
$clearArray = Arr::undot($flattened);
```

Comment: переписал, чтобы было покороче

Comment: @YahenKib а если не удалять, а просто возвращать определенные три значения,   так еще короче будет

Comment: я добавил $value, ибо до этого он не удалял ключи,   а видимо воспринимал $key как значение,  а не ключ